# how do I describe this circuit ?

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics

[image]

This is a circuit designed by my friend

How do I describe this circuit in words? 
The only thing I know is that this circuit has astable 555 timer and that it's meant to create noise from the speakers.

Comment: "Confusingly drawn" would be my words. You already seem to have the rest sewn up.

Comment: Describe the circuit by its most remarkable features: call it "the 555 circuit that runs on 1V and uses a 40µ\$\Omega\$ resistor".

Comment: Can you even buy a 40µΩ resistor?

Comment: @Finbarr about 8 foot of 0000 guage wire would do the trick...

Comment: If the blue resistor is some form of resistor under test, this circuit might work as a acoustic ohm meter by modulating the pulse width.  Or I could be completely wrong, I've just gotten up and haven't had any caffeine. :-)

Comment: What does your friend describe it as? Was it your friend who guessed values or really you. No need to be shy. Honesty is the best policy I find.

Comment: @Andyaka good point : back to the friend....

Comment: My friend probably guessed them but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1):

> The only thing I know is that this circuit has astable 555 timer and that it's meant to create noise from the speakers

Like so.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I went about describing a circuit little while ago. Please add/edit to this you experienced folks.

1. Describe the function

   a. what the circuit is trying to achieve

   b. how the circuit achieves the functions

   c. limitations the circuit may have
2. Describe the input(s)
3. Describe the output(s)
4. Power supply requirements

The circuit is designed to produce noise for a speaker using a 555 timer configured in astable/monostable/other mode. The circuit uses a specialized 40 uOhm resistor. The function of which cannot be disclosed for security reasons. The system is powered by a 1V power supply.